# IE vs Other browser offsetHeight and scrollHeight

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, overflow, frame

So I have a resize handler that resizes some column headers depending on if there is a scroll on the right or not (overflow vs not overflow) to adjust the spacing to account for the scroll. The resize works when I'm changing the size of the frame to make the frame overflow vs not overflow. However when I'm modifying the columns in some way that doesn't affect the frame size, I still need the resize but the resize will bug out. Heres the pseudo code I have of a snippet of the resize.

```
if (display != "none") {
    if (frame.offsetHeight >= frame.scrollHeight) {
        display = "none"
    }
} else {
    if (frame.offsetHeight < frame.scrollHeight) {
        display = ""
    }
}
```

So the problem is that, when the resize handler is called when the frame size is not changed, in FF, Chrome and Safari, the scrollHeight is 1 more than `frame.offsetHeight` (ie. if `offsetHeight` is 100px, `scrollHeight` is actually 101px) but in IE, the offsetHeight and scrollHeight are the same, thus making the condition when `display == ""` and `frame.offsetHeight < frame.scrollHeight` to fail. Are these properties for IE and other browsers handled differently?

Comment: Short answer to all browser problems: don't use IE.

Comment: or, use jQuery and support all browsers, including IE

Comment: Never, EVER trust IE to do anything right.

Comment: I still would like to get it to work though. I have now narrowed down the problem some more. Its not just 1 px, that was a case specific example. So the problem would appear is that IE's scrollheight and offsetheight would be the same if overflow occurs. Say i have elements in the div that's 400px. I shrink the frame to 200px height. In non-IE, scrollHeight == 400 and offsetHeight == 200. However in IE, scrollHeight == offsetHeight == 200 :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing `frame.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight` to get the height? The height of the content, rather than the iFrame tag will work better for this.